# Update sharepoint page content while applying variations

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a sharepoint site which is developed with SharePoint server 2010.
I have applied multi language options using Variations. my source language is "en" and target is "fr", I am successfully able to replicate page creation in "fr" site. But contents are still the same. I want a "Translate language" option in Ribbon control. OR anything else which automatically translate my content of "en" to "fr" when I do "Update"/"create" from "Publish".

Anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Plan variations (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262404.aspx)

> > Although variations can be used for multilingual solutions, **the variations feature does not translate pages**. To use variations for creating multilingual content, you can use workflows to route content for translation by another team or third-party vendor after the content is copied to target sites.

Comment: Yes, I know. Is there any way I can achieve automatic translation OR a "Ttranslate" option in ribbon control. ?

Comment: yes, I have wiki pages and my site is in English and French. I want like, When "admin" add/update any new pages/content in the "pages" section of "view all site contents". and go for publishing (Publish=> "create/update), along with creating a new page the content should also be translated. Admin should not need to go to the "fr" site and manually edit page and translate the content.

Comment: Who or what should translate the content? Google Translate, Bing Translator, Babel Fish, the admin's assistant, a translator hired from an external company?

Comment: I don't want to use any 3rd party tools. I want sharepoint itself to translate content. I have mentioned in my post that i want "automatically translate my content of "en" to "fr" when I do "Update"/"create" from "Publish". Is there any way in sharepoint to achieve this ? For example, If I can do this by using any work flow or event receiver or anything else... Is that possible ?

Comment: @XYZ: Yes, but you'll need to create your **own translation engine** in the workflow. You need to understand that *starting* the translation process is easy, the *translation process* is the hard part and SharePoint has no built-in translation features. In short - there is no way to achieve what you need in a reasonable time without 3rd party tools or services.